# Laravel Javascript Image Swap Dropdown List

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

Right now i'm develop eCommerce Shopping Site using Laravel 5.0 , this is for my fyp , there is long way to go .. anyway .

And , i make product show page

This is my controller :

```
     public function getView($id)
{
    return view('store.show')->with('products', Product::find($id))->with('categories',Category::all())->with('db',Product::all())->with('options', Gambar::where('product_id','=',$id)->lists('name', 'img'));
}
```

As you can see, on the end of the line have code **lists('name', 'img')**

It will list out the column name and image values into a List

Everything were works perfectly accept , i need to make drop down list with image change on select .

Look on the code for my drop down list and imageswap :

```
    <div class="form-group">

     {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) !!}
     {!! Form::label('Link Category') !!}<br />
     {!! Form::select('product_id',(['0' => 'Select an Option'] + $options),null,['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'dlist', 'onChange' => 'swapImage()']) !!}
     {!! Form::close() !!}

     <script type="text/javascript">
     function swapImage(){
     var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
     var dropd = document.getElementById("dlist");
     image.src = dropd.value;
     };
     </script>
    </div>
```

And this code where the image will appear base on select (products->image were main image , not seed from dropdown list :

```
 <img id="imageToSwap" src="{{asset($products->image)}}"  />
```

The flow of List in controller works , but it give this in view source chrome :

```
<img id="imageToSwap" src="img/upload/20-3-291-image-1.jpg"  />
```

So the image not appear in page , it should appear like this :

```
<img id="imageToSwap" src="localhost:8000/img/upload/20-3-291-image-1.jpg"  />
```

The question is , how to return the "img" with laravel asset {{asset()}}, so the image can display perfectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the communication between laravel and javascript.

As you point, you use **lists('name', 'img')**: the asset prefix will not be added there.

Hence, when you do `image.src = dropd.value;` the source of the image doesn't have the asset prefix.

I see 2 possibilities:

- either you do some treatment on your list before sending it:
  `lists('name', 'img')->map(asset)` (with the [map](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-map) method --not sure if it's available for laravel 5.0)
- Or you add it in your javascript: `image.src = "{{asset()}}/" + dropd.value;`

Comment: error when apply image.src = "{{asset()}}/" + dropd.value;

ErrorException in helpers.php line 81:
Missing argument 1 for asset(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb2\storage\framework\views\a3ea3da5b741ea4eca39686d1e2d05b0 on line 100 and defined (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb2\resources\views\store\show.blade.php)